# OpenSeaDragon FullScreenMode in mobile

Tags: android, openseadragon

I am using OpenSeaDragon to show images on my website. With the desktop browser everything is working correct. Also in device mode with the DevTools from chrome. But when I switch to a real mobile device, I can't change to fullscreen mode.

The view try to expand, the buttons slide to the top, but cancels itself immadiately.

I have build a small Android application with a webview to access the website.

I even don't know, if it is a Android issue or an OpenSeaDragon issue. Any hint what I should check could be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a link to a repro? I tried it in Chrome on an Android phone with http://openseadragon.github.io/ and it seems to be working there.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried it again and it worked, but only in browser. Not in a WebView.

Comment: Oh, I see! I imagine to get full screen mode to work in a WebView you'll have to do some UI work in the Android app itself. I'm not familiar enough with Android code to advise you on that, but you might look for general information on how to make an Android app go fullscreen.

Comment: I have faked a full screen mode on iOS as pinch just closes the full screen and I don't have a iPad to further debug. I set the visibility and toolbar to hidden on body and then set my div container to full window with important set for the visibility just for the div so it shows. You might want to take this route to fake a full screen.

Comment: I was trying something similar, but then I saw the full-page mode. This works for me either and there is no trouble with the webview.